# How to load related entity of external data source in Lightswitch (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have 2 tables which are both in an Azure SQL Database which is connected to my Lightswitch Sharepoint app. I am doing some manipulation of the data in code, and it appears to be working, except that when I load the entities from one table, I am not able to see the related entities in the other.

Basically, I have a products table and an invoice lines table. Each invoice line record contains a product code, which relates to the products table PK. I have defined the relationship in Lightswitch, but when I load the invoice line record, I can't see the product information.

My code is as follows:

```
// Select invoice and get products
myapp.AddEditServiceRecord.InvoicesByCustomer_ItemTap_execute = function (screen) {
    screen.ServiceRecord.InvoiceNumber = screen.InvoicesByCustomer.selectedItem.INVO_NO;

    // Delete existing lines (if any)
    screen.ServiceDetails.data.forEach(function (line) {
        line.deleteEntity();
    });

    // Add products for selected invoice
    screen.getInvoiceLinesByNumber().then(function (invLines) {
        invLines.data.forEach(function (invLine) {
            invLine.getProduct().then(function (invProduct) {
                var newLine = new myapp.ServiceDetail();

                newLine.ServiceRecord = screen.ServiceRecord;
                newLine.ProductCode = invLine.ProductCode;
                newLine.ProductDescription = invProduct.Description;
                newLine.CasesOrdered = invLine.Cases;
            });            
        });
    });
};
```

The idea is that a list of invoices are on the screen 'InvoicesByCustomer', and the user clicks one to add the details of that invoice to the 'ServiceRecord' table. If I comment out the `newLine.ProductDescription = invProduct.Description` line it works perfectly in adding the correct product codes and cases values. I have also tried a few other combinations of the below code, but in each case the related product entity appears as `undefined` in the Javascript debugger.

**EDIT:** I also read this article on including related data (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/05/29/lightswitch-tips-amp-tricks-on-query-performance.aspx) and noticed the section on 'Static Spans'. I checked and this was set to 'Auto (Excluded)' so I changed it to 'Included', but unfortunately this made no difference. I'm still getting the `invProduct is undefined` message. I also tried simply `invLine.Product.Description` but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case was a simple one. My data was wrong, and therefore Lightswitch was doing it's job correctly!

In my `Invoices` table, the product code was something like `'A123'` whereas in my `Products` table, the product code was `'A123          '` (padded with spaces on the right). When doing SQL queries against the data, it was able to match the records but Lightswitch (correctly) saw the 2 fields as different and so could not relate them.

I may have wasted several hours on this, but it's not wasted when something has been learnt...or so I'll tell myself!